# Динамически формируемый интерфейс пользователя

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Возможно ли с помощью Web форм .Net создавать динамически формируемый интерфейс?
Пример:
Допустим у Вас есть потребность в создании приложения, которое выводит на страницу вопросы и ответы тестирования персонала или социального опроса. При этом, сам вопрос и ответ может формироваться различными элементами: например, вопрос в виде теста, картинки, видео, ответ в виде текста, выпадающего списка, списка радио кнопок и т.п. Все данные хранятся в базе данных и при добавлении нового вопроса и ответа на него эти данные выводятся автоматически при следующем обновлении страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не назвал это так уж динамически формируемым, раз все данные в БД.

По сабжу: у вас есть WebForm, у нее есть `Page_Load`. Допустим, в хэндлере Page_Load вы делаете некий select из Table1 в БД. Если вы каким то образом между обновлениями страницы сделаете insert в эту самую Table1, то при обновлении select будет содержать и новые данные.

Почитайте про [жизненный цикл ASP.NET страницы](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Кажется я не правильно выразился) Точнее, если у вас есть вопросы:
1. Вопрос 1; - Текст
2. Вопрос 2; - Текст
3. Вопрос n; - Текст
И Вы хотите вывести их например в элемент Label, то Вам потребуется:
1. Создать прямо в коде отдельный элемент для каждой полученной записи из БД;
или
2. Сделать некий шаблон, который будет использоваться для динамического создания отдельного элемента и отображения в нем данных.
Таким образом можно вывести данные на страницу.
Теперь Вы подобным образом выводите из БД ответы для каждого вопроса.
Вопрос, как используя второй вариант занести полученные ответы в БД?